# how to fill in gaps of selected rows using linq?

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I need to make rows with fixed number of cells. I made table with 24 cells for 24 hours of the day. however, the rows retrieved not always have 24 cells.

my question is how to fill in gaps of not completed rows. using linq.

for example I have this table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[driversTasks](
Id int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    [FromTime] [time](7) NOT NULL,
    [ToTime] [time](7) NOT NULL,
    [AtDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [Destination] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [IsConfirmed] bit NOT NULL,
    [EmployeeId] int NOT NULL,
    [DriverId] int NOT NULL)


INSERT INTO driversTasks
           ([FromTime],[ToTime],[AtDate],[Destination],[IsConfirmed],[DriverId],[EmployeeId])
     VALUES
('02:30:00','03:40:00', '2022-08-23','',0, 1, 1),
('04:50:00','05:10:00', '2022-08-23','',0, 1, 1),
('05:40:00','06:00:00', '2022-08-23','',0, 1, 1),
('06:30:00','07:15:00', '2022-08-23','',0, 1, 1),
('07:40:00','08:00:00', '2022-08-23','',0, 1, 1),
('09:48:00','10:40:00', '2022-08-23','',0, 1, 1),
('11:12:00','12:40:00', '2022-08-23','',0, 1, 1),
('13:00:00','14:00:00', '2022-08-23','',0, 1, 1),
('15:30:00','17:40:00', '2022-08-23','',0, 1, 1),
('19:50:00','21:22:00', '2022-08-23','',0, 1, 1),
('22:30:00','00:00:00', '2022-08-23','',0, 1, 1)
```

[image: and it displays values like this]

First: [FromTime] should start from index 2 not 1
Second: the row souldn't stop at index 12 it should give empty values until 24.

the linq that i'm using is

```
_context.driversTasks.OrderBy(o => o.FromTime).ToList();
```

but I don't know how to make data retrieved like that

"", 02:30:00, "", "", 04:50:00, 05:40:00, ...etc until 00:00:00 for index 24

Updadte ...

here is how I display my data

```
  <tbody id="mytable">
        <tr>
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {

                if (@Model.IndexOf(item) == 0)
                {
                    <th scope="row">@item.driv.Name</th>
                }
                <td data-from="@item.FromTime" data-to="@item.ToTime">@(Model.IndexOf(item)+1) - @item.FromTime</td>
            }
        </tr>
  </tbody>
```

Comment: It doesn't sound like this has anything to do with LINQ or with the data itself, but rather how you're building the UI.  If each cell of the UI corresponds to a specific "time slot" and each cell should always show something, then you probably want an explicit loop from 1-24 to create your cells, and in each iteration of the loop find the (potentially null) data value that goes in that cell.  Don't make your data more complex, make your UI use the data effectively.

Comment: @David I updated the question. would you please help me with that

Comment: This is mostly theoretical and would require some tinkering/testing on your part, but... Instead of looping over the model, try an explicit loop over your UI expectation.  You can even make it explicit by, for example, the *minutes* value in the day.  Something like: `for (var m = 0; m < 1440; m += 30)`  A loop somewhat like this would allow you to fill every cell.  Then within that loop, based on the current `m` (minutes) value, *find* the item in `Model` which should go in that cell.  If none is found, display an empty cell.  Otherwise, display what's found.